# DynamoDBMapper mapping composite objects implementing an interface

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

Consider an interface with several implementations

```
Public interface A {}

@DynamoDBDocument
Public class C1 implements A {
    variables…
}
@DynamoDBDocument
Public class C2 implements A {
    variables…
}

@DynamoDBTable
Public class TopLevelClass {
    A obj;   //It can be any implementation C1, C2 ….
    //Getter and setter of A 
}
```

Saving an object of type C1 in the dynamoDB works fine, but we are unable to deserialize it back. Jackson does it by adding a @class attribute to the json to help it figure out which implementation to instantiate, however DynamoDBMapper has no idea and ends up trying to instantiate an object of A which obviously fails as it’s just an interface.

Is there a way we can achieve this? We don’t want to use marshallers as it will just deserialize the whole object as string and defeats the purpose of DynamoDBDocument type.